Limit text to certain word
I have made a PHP script like this:
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <?php $articles = getArticle(3); ?>

        <div class="row borderrowindex">
            <?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="newslink" href="artikel.php?title=<?= urlencode($article['title']) ?>">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <img class="articlecard-photo" src="assets/img/background.jpeg" alt="Article Image">
                                <h4 class="card-title text-center"><?= $article['title'] ?></h4>
                                <p class="card-text fullText"><?= $article['article'] ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/artlimit.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

And script of artlimit.js like this:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const fullTextElements = document.querySelectorAll('.fullText');
    const wordLimit = 5; // Adjust the word limit as needed

    fullTextElements.forEach(element => {
        let text = element.textContent;
        let words = text.split(' ');

        if (words.length > wordLimit) {
            let truncatedText = words.slice(0, wordLimit).join(' ') + '...';
            element.textContent = truncatedText;
        }
    });
});


From the js file it was supposed limiting the word shown only 5 word but when I apply it, all of the text based on <?= $article['article'] ?> shown not limited to 5 word. The data are fetched from database and the data also save as text in the database itself.
The example of <?= $article['article'] ?> are like this:
<p><span style='font-size:18px;'><strong>Amsterdam</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></p>

<p><img alt='' src='/media/images/WhatsApp%20Image%202022-11-10%20at%2008.15.57.jpeg' style='width: 400px; height: 300px;' /></p>

<p><img alt='' src='/media/images/WhatsApp%20Image%202022-11-10%20at%2008.56.46.jpeg' style='width: 400px; height: 225px;' /></p>

Can someone help me what's wrong with this?

I added a simple console.log() of the extracted text, and a console.dir() of the extracted words, and the problem is immediately apparent.  No text is detected with the HTML you've shown, so no words are detected in that text, so words.length > wordLimit is false, and no truncation happens.
So what could the problem be?
Your HTML looks like:
<p class="card-text fullText"><p>....</p></p>

There's a pretty obvious potential problem there - nesting <p>s like that looks invalid to me.  A quick search confirms that yes, nesting <p>s like that is invalid.
Simply removing the extra nested <p> solves the problem.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const fullTextElements = document.querySelectorAll('.fullText');
  const wordLimit = 5; // Adjust the word limit as needed

  fullTextElements.forEach(element => {
    let text = element.textContent;
    let words = text.split(' ');
    console.log('start', text);
    console.dir(words);

    if (words.length > wordLimit) {
      let truncatedText = words.slice(0, wordLimit).join(' ') + '...';
      element.textContent = truncatedText;
    }
  });
});
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row borderrowindex">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a class="newslink" href="artikel.php?title=foo">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title text-center">
                Foo Bar Title
              </h4>
              <p class="card-text fullText"><span style='font-size:18px;'><strong>Amsterdam</strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Some suggestions:

Please try to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, and include it in your question.  PHP isn't the problem here, so your PHP code is irrelevant - all that matters is the rendered HTML and the JS.  In this case the PHP code even conceals the problem, because the problem is in the HTML included in the PHP variables.  Likewise we don't need 3 of them - a single example <div> would demonstrate the problem.

Try to do some basic debugging before posting a quesiton.  The first thing you could try is using console.log(), or alert(), which would lead you straight to the path where you're likely to solve the problem yourself.  We all start somewhere, if you're not familiar with console.log() or how to debug Javascript, start with some Javascript tutorials to learn those basics.



Sorry I've got unclear about my question here but thanks, I will try to remove the nested 
